# Standard GARCH(1,1) model with external regressors

Tags: time-series, garch, models

I have a queastion how does a standard GARCH(1,1) model with external regressors in mean and variance euqations look like ?

I know that standard GARCH(1,1) model without external regressors has the following form:
\begin{equation*}
r_t = \mu + \epsilon_t
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\epsilon_t = \sigma_t z_t
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\sigma_t^2 = \omega + \alpha_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2 + \beta_1 \epsilon_{t-1}^2
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
z_t \sim N(0, 1).
\end{equation*}
But where should I include mentioned external regressors in mean and variance ? And how does the model look then ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

An external regressor in the mean specification can be added to the mean specification, i.e. $$r_t = \mu + \varepsilon_t + \theta x_t $$.

An external regressor in the variance specification can be added to the variance specification, i.e. $$\sigma^2_t = \omega + \alpha \sigma_{t-1}^2 + \beta \varepsilon_{t-1}^2 + \theta x_{t}$$